# When click mouse on 1st <div> it must be move back and 2nd <div> must be show

Tags: javascript, jquery

CODE:

```
<div id="main" height="500px" width="500px" style="margin-left:500px; margin-top:100px; position:absolute;">
<div id="div1" style="display:block;position:absolute">
    <p style="background-color:#ff9c00; border-radius: 8px; height: 70px; width: 299px;"></p>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:block;position:absolute;margin-left:25px;">
    <p style="background-color:#afca37; border-radius: 8px; height: 70px; width: 299px;"></p>
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:block; position:absolute; margin-left:50px;">
    <p style="background-color:#e11d4e; border-radius: 8px; height: 70px; width: 299px;"></p>
</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:block; position:absolute; margin-left:75px;">
    <p style="background-color:#a751df; border-radius: 8px;height: 70px; width: 299px;"></p>
</div>
<div id="div5" style="display:block; position:absolute; margin-left:100px;">
    <p style="background-color:#f6d12c; border-radius: 8px; height: 70px; width: 299px;"></p>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(div1).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div1").animate({right:'2px'});
    });
    $(div2).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div2").animate({right:'2px'});
    });
    $(div3).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div3").animate({right:'2px'});
    });
```

It's not working; it moves only the left side.

Comment: Is `/^div[0-9]$/` defined anywhere in your script(s)?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: What do you mean move back?

Comment: move back... and show 2 nd div.

Comment: lovely use of inline styles, try using CSS to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I somehow understand what you are trying to do. I tested your code on jsfiddle and it's working but does not animate as expected because the `right` position is not set so it has the default `'auto'` and jQuery has a problem animating from that position.

I would also suggest you animate the `left` property instead:

```
$('#main > div').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({       
        /* Im getting index value of the hovered div 
        multiply by 25 (the margin-left differential) 
        so all div will position on the same spot when animated.
        350 is just random you define whatever you like
        */
        left: -350-($(this).index()*25)
    }).siblings().animate({
        left: 0
    });
});
```

You can see the demo here: [**jsfiddle.net/bDJYF/**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDJYF/)

However as you can see on the demo the `<div>`'s are animating over and back again. This is because we are executing it on `mouseover()` event, it seems it's not suited for your design. If you can switch to `click()` then you can see a good result: [**jsfiddle.net/bDJYF/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDJYF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You havent closed the document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(div1).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div1").animate({right:'2px'});
    });
    $(div2).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div2").animate({right:'2px'});
    });
    $(div3).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div3").animate({right:'2px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(div1).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div1").animate({right:'10px'});
    });
    $(div2).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div2").animate({right:'8px'});
    });
    $(div3).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div3").animate({right:'6px'});
    });
     $(div4).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div4").animate({right:'4px'});
    });
     $(div5).mouseover(function(){
        $("#div5").animate({right:'2px'});
    });

    });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use z-index. Toggle z-index between two division on mouse click. 
You can use below code on mouseclick on div tag..

```
document.getElementById('div1Id').style.zIndex=1;
document.getElementById('div2Id').style.zIndex=2;
```